# Nested object routing with ServiceStack

Tags: rest, routes, servicestack

I would like to set up something like below as it is a cleaner POCO design, but it seems that I can only make this work by creating a `UserId` property of `int` instead of the lazily loaded POCO.

```
[Route("/Accounts", "GET")]  //Where I want to be able to do /Accounts?UserId=1234 
[Route("/Accounts/{Id}", "GET")] 
public class Account
{
  public User User {get;set;}
  public int Id {get;set;}
  ...
}

public class User
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  ...Lazily loaded values
}
```

**Is this the only option?**

```
public class Account
{
  public int UserId {get;set;}
  public int Id {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the Account class your request dto? See the wiki to see how to decorate your request dto with routes, https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing

Comment: Downvoted because I already showed my understanding of the basic routing (which is what is in the wiki). I want a nested item to be identifiable (`Account.User.Id`)

Comment: Just trying to help out. FTIW I have only seen examples and unit tests that do what is mentioned in the wiki.